# Matching link with regex

Tags: php, regex

I want to match link with regex until first space or `<` occur.
I tried this regex

```
\b(((http|ftp)(.)?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?example\.com([^\s|<]+)?)\b
```

But the problem  with this regex is that it is also matching `example.com.au`.
So what i want to match

```
example.com                      // match
example.com/somelink/link        // match

example.com.au                   // do not match
example.com.au/somelink/link     // do not match
```

match till first space or `<` occur

Comment: So you specifically want to match `example.com`? `example.com.au` is a valid host.

Comment: @KennethK. yes i want to match `example.com` but not `example.com.au` also match every thing till first space occur like this `example.com `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that will match http://example.com/whatever but not http://example.com.au/whatever.

```
/\b(((http|ftp)(.)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?example\.com(?!\.[\w\d])(\/[^\s<]*)?)\b/
```

This was tested against this text:

```
Match http://example.com/ but not http://example.com.au
This is a sentence about http://example.com/.
http://example.com<
http://example.com/asdf.asdf.asdf/ asdf
http://example.computer
```

It uses a negative lookahead to specifically exclude example.com followed by `\.[\w\d]`.

Comment: looks pretty impressive. Let me try it first.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell it you don't want to match any dots after .com

```
\b(((http|ftp)(.)?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?example\.com([^\s|<|\.]+)?)\b
```

Or get more clever and tell it you expect a forward slash after .com if there is anything after .com

```
\b(((http|ftp)(.)?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?example\.com(\/[^\s|<]+)?)\b
```

Comment: Yes no dot after `.com`, but want to match everything after `.com` till first space occur. Yes expecting a forward slash

Comment: The second one I mentioned should work for you just fine then.

Comment: the above regex 1st one still matches `example.com` in `example.com.au`